# About the FILE * streams and how fputc() works

Tags: c, file-pointer

I wonder about the operation of `FILE` pointer `f` and how the function `fputc` works.

First, when I open a file (I have not been working on it yet, like writing or reading). What position of `f` in the file? Is it before the first character?

Second, when I use:

```
fseek(f, -1, SEEK_CUR);
fputc(' ', f);
```

what position of my pointer `f` now?

Comment: Before doing `fputc()` you want to check whether `fseek()`ing succeeded.

Comment: Also reading documentation helps. You might like to run `man fopen`. It's also in the Standard: http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.5.3

Comment: And you can always use `ftell()`. Whether it's helpful or not that's another question.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the manuals should help you.

For `fopen`: the stream is positioned at the beginning of the file. Except for mode like `'a'`

For `fseek`: that function can fail, you have to test the return value; and it is not difficult to imagine that you cannot obtain a negative offset.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the file, the current position is `0`, **at** the first character.

If you try to `fseek` before the beginning of the file, `fseek` will fail and return `-1`.

Note that if you seek backwards on a text file, there is no guarantee that is can succeed.  On linux and/or for a binary stream, assuming you are not at the start of the stream, opened in write mode for a real file, after the sequence

```
fseek(f, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
fputc(' ', f);
```

the position of the stream will be the same as before the `fseek`.

But consider this seemingly simpler example:

```
fputc('\n', f);
fseek(f, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
```

On systems such as Windows, where `'\n'` will at some point be converted into a sequence of 2 bytes `<CR><LF>`, what do you think it should do?

Because of all these possibilities for failure (and a few more exotic ones), you should always test the return value of `fseek` and try to minimize its use.

Comment: @DDK: there is no support for *insert mode*.  See my response to your new question.

Answer (score 1):

- When accessing files through C, the first necessity is to have a way to access   the files. For C File I/O you need to use a FILE pointer, which will let the program keep track of the file being accessed. For Example:

  ```
   FILE *fp;
  ```
- To open a file you need to use the fopen function, which returns a FILE pointer. Once you've opened a file, you can use the FILE pointer to let the compiler perform input and output functions on the file.

  ```
  FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
  ```
- Here filename is string literal which you will use to name your file and mode can have one of the following values

  ```
  w  - open for writing (file need not exist)
  a   - open for appending (file need not exist)
  r+ - open for reading and writing, start at beginning
  w+ - open for reading and writing (overwrite file)
  a+ - open for reading and writing (append if file exists)
  ```
- Following is the declaration for fseek() function.

  ```
  int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence)

  SEEK_SET    Beginning of file
  SEEK_CUR    Current position of the file pointer
  SEEK_END    End of file
  ```
- Following fputc() example :

  ```
  /* fputc example: alphabet writer */
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main ()
   {
      FILE * pFile;
       char c;

      pFile = fopen ("alphabet.txt","w");
       if (pFile!=NULL) {

        for (c = 'A' ; c <= 'Z' ; c++)
        fputc ( c , pFile );

        fclose (pFile);
      }
      return 0;
     }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your current position/offset for an example if your file pointer was on **100th** **offset** and you write `fseek(f, -1, SEEK_CUR);` and the offset will be at 99th position, and then you write space on **99th** position, after writing space using `fputc(' ', f);` file pointer's offset will be **100th** again.